# Restoring a table from session state in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

Alright, so here's the skinny I guess. I've got a small shopping cart web application that I've been toying around with in ASP.NET and C#. It's pretty basic right now; it's three pages at the moment and the process is basically pick your item, pick how many you want, then add it/them to your cart.

First two pages work *flawlessly*...the cart is where I'm running into trouble. The jist of the cart page is that it dynamically builds a table with the relevant information about the product added. And every time a user goes back to the item page and selects another product it *should* add it to the last line on the cart table.

I'm using session state in order to keep track of the cart between page visits to the cart page. When I first start the page and add the first item it works perfectly and I get what I should see on the page (see screenshot below):

[Screenshot of first item added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFuT.jpg)

Unfortunately, from there it goes all down hill. Once you either try and add another item, or even just click the 'Cart' menu link while viewing the cart all the inputted information goes away. (BTW, don't know if it's relevant or not, but clicking on the 'Cart' menu link before adding anything to the cart does not produce the same behavior. So I've, hopefully, narrowed it down to it being something that is happening *after* an item is added.)

[Screenshot of cart after simply clicking the 'Cart' menu link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLVT6.jpg)

This is the code block from my cart's C# code behind file that's responsible for adding data to the table on the page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class viewCart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["myTable"] != null)
        {
            tblCartItems = (Table)Session["myTable"];

            for (int i = 1; i < tblCartItems.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tblCartItems.Rows.Add(tblCartItems.Rows[i]);
            }
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["qty"] != null)
        {
            string item = Request.QueryString["item"];
            int qty = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["qty"]);
            double price = double.Parse(Request.QueryString["price"]);

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(item));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(qty.ToString()));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(price.ToString()));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell(extPrice(qty, price).ToString()));
            row.Cells.Add(addCell("<asp:Button ID=\"btn_RemoveRow\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"Remove Item\" />"));

            tblCartItems.Rows.Add(row);

            Session["myTable"] = tblCartItems;
        }  
    } 
}
```

The initial table (which is a standard, simple ASP.NET table, nothing super fancy) that you would see if you went to the cart page w/o adding any items is just the table headers, and these are coded in the cart's .aspx file, not in the code behind. So all the code behind is doing is taking data I'm passing from the item.aspx page (the page where you select how many items you want) and passing info to the cart page via a URL query string. I'm also using a master page with this little app (in case that's relevant at all).

I'm like 95% sure I'm on the right track and that I'm just missing some stupid little thing. If anybody can point me in the right direction I would be super grateful since this has been driving me nuts all day!

Comment: Why we are storing whole html table in the session, why don't we just store the items or list of items in the session and then bind it to the grid, repeater etc

Comment: the problem can be with the condition IsPostback, Have you debugging it?

Comment: @HaseebAsif I've thought about storing just the rows I add since I've already got the headers being built in the .aspx file. (That was why I started the for loop at i = 1, so that it would pull the data row out instead of the header row).

As for the IsPostBack condition, when I debug it the program goes into the if(!IsPostBack) statement but then skips over the two inner ones on the first run of the page only (which I think is what I want since when seeing the page first there's no reason to fire those two).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've chosen the same variable name for both the table on your page, and the variable you're pulling out of the session state.

So on first load Session["myTable"] is null, and you drop into the 2nd block, construct the HTML table and store it to the session state. Then on the 2nd load, you pull the HTML table from the session state, and try to overwrite the table on the page itself (you then copy the rows from the session object to itself).

```
    if (Session["myTable"] != null)
    {
        Table tblCartItemsSession = (Table)Session["myTable"];

        for (int i = 1; i < tblCartItemsSession.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            tblCartItems.Rows.Add(tblCartItemsSession.Rows[i]);
        }
    }
```

The above change I think should work, though I haven't tested it.

Also, it's not best practice to store the HTML object, you should create a Cart object, and then write some conversion logic to display the table from the Cart object, here's an example to help with this.

First, the dummy object:

```
public class CartItem 
{
    public string item { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

Then the top section changes to:

```
List<CartItem> items = new List<CartItem>();
if (Session["myCart"] != null)
{
    Items = (List<CartItem>)Session["myCart"];
}
```

Then, you add to your list with the new object (made from the querystring variables)

```
items.Add(new CartItem() {
   item = item,
   qty = qty,
   price = price
});
```

Then, display the list of items, I'd suggest using a grid view for this, it just makes it a bit easier (see: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7eb164/gridview-control-in-Asp-Net/), and finally save the list of items to your session variable

Comment: This worked...sort of. But I can only add two rows. When I start to add more items it keeps replacing the bottom row.

Also, making a cart object is a really good idea. But wouldn't I have to still save the table? I can't set a finite number of cart objects to save the session state since I wouldn't know ahead of time how many items are going to be added.

Comment: I've edited the answer and given you an example with objects to help, this saves just the raw data to the session, rather than the HTML objects.

Answer (score -2):

This might not help the original poster but might help somebody else. I was in exactly the same position, with a deadline to meet, and subpar c# knowledge, so I used the good old trick: I created a shopping cart table in my database, and bound it to the gridview in the webpage, with the proper controls to add, clear, reset, etc.

It might not be the best solution, but it sure helped me out.